# Are there any tutorials on how to add details to textures?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture

I'm trying to add detail to this texture like making the lips more realistic but I'm not sure how I can achieve it.

Can I merge another image onto lips or would that mess with the texture.

Edit: I am using Photoshop CC 2018

[image: Texture of 3d Model]

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: @ZachSaucier Photoshop CC 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can add textures by merging images. There probably are tutorials, but it's not really difficult to imagine how it could be done.

A fairly simple method:

1. Find or take a photo of real lips

[image]

2. Create a texture by using the high pass filter

[image]

3. Erase everything except the lips
4. Scale and position the texture over the lips
5. Set the layer blending mode to *Overlay*

Note: If the lips don't quite match/align, you could use the liquify filter to distort them to fit.

Here's an example showing steps 4 to 5. The result is quite subtle, which is probably key to not making it look too fake.

[image]

Comment: thank you that's gotten me closer to the result I was looking for